# Have BeautifulSoup output <br> instead of <br/>

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have some HTML I modify using BeautifulSoup 4 (4.3.2 currently).  When converting the modified soup to a string, all `br` Elements are written as `<br/>`:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<p>Paragraph containing<br>line break</p>')
>>> soup.p
<p>Paragraph containing<br/>line break</p>
>>> str(soup.p)
'<p>Paragraph containing<br/>line break</p>'
```

That's ok for HTML 5, but not necessarily for HTML 4, and for my use case; I'd like to produce the output like it used to be.

The `formatter` argument to the `prettify` and `encode` methods seems to affect string contents only.

Is it possible to tell BeautifulSoup *not* to produce self-closing tags?
Or would I need to write a function myself to walk the soup and create such a string?

Comment: When I do the above commands on Python 3.4.1 with BeautifulSoup 4.3.2 it gives me <br> and </br> ?? : '<p>Paragraph containing<br>line break</br></p>'

Comment: This is strange, and I'd consider it an error; the `br` element is supposed to be empty. I used Python 2.7.5 and `lxml`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, `BeautifulSoup` has either tags that are opened and then closed, or self-closing tags. There is no such thing as a non-closed tag, as you want `<br>` to be.

Long time ago, [someone tried to apply a patch](http://henry.precheur.org/python/beautiful_soup.html) to make `prettify()` output `br` tag properly for HTML 4.

The easiest solution would be to remove closing part manually:

```
>>> data = '<p>Paragraph containing<br>line break</p>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
>>> str(soup).replace('</br>', '')
'<p>Paragraph containing<br>line break</p>'
```

Which is, really not a beautiful and reliable solution.

A better way to handle it would be to create your own *tree builder class* and control the way `br` tag is constructed in `handle_starttag()` and `handle_endtag()` methods.

Comment: Ah, I suppose you mean http://effbot.org/elementtree/elementtree-treebuilder.htm#tag-ET.TreeBuilder; I'll try this.  So far, I miserably failed when trying to subclass `xml.etree.cElementTree.TreeBuilder`: "TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases" for a start ...

Comment: I'll take the "no" as the answer; an own "tree builder class" (which would need to be explained in more detail) or function would be needed. Luckily I don't seem to need it very urgently ;-)

Comment: @Tobias sorry it took so long to answer :) What if you make a separate question about the writing a custom "tree builder class"? Might be an interesting challenge. Thanks.